# Would this be a legitimate Epsilon delta proof for the limit of 1/x

Tags: limits, solution-verification

Would this be a legitimate proof, or did I make a mistake?

Lets say you have a question like prove that $$\lim_{ x\to2}\frac 1x = \frac12.$$

so $$|f(x) - L| = |1/x - 1/2| = |x-2| \cdot \frac1{|2x|}.$$  Now if you say $\delta<1,$ $1/|2x|$ is always less than 1 so
$$|x-2|\cdot\frac 1{|2x|} < |x-2| < \epsilon$$
so just make  $\delta = \epsilon,$ (and min $1$)

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “and min $1.$” We usually write the condition you want as $\delta=\min(\epsilon,1).$

Comment: I would say: “$1/|2x|<1$ for $|x-2|<1.$”  Not “always.” I knew what you intended, but it pays to be precise about which “always” you mean.

Comment: To convince yourself that the proof works, what happens if you supply different values of $\epsilon>0$? Does your argument still hold up?

Comment: The frustrating thing about limit proofs is that we often prove them backwards like this, but the **real** proof is forwards. The stuff where you work out what $\delta$ should be is just research. You need to prove if $|x-2|<\min(1,\epsilon)$ then the difference is less than $\epsilon.$ It is hidden in the “research,” but in a backwards order.

Comment: the details are fine. is it a legitimate proof? in my opinion no, in fact there's no proof here at all - it's like you had an outline for the proof, inserted details, and then _erased_ the actual proof. (For example, of course I know what you mean by $\epsilon$. But if the idea is to write correct proofs, me knowing what you mean doesn't count - "officially" when I see that $\epsilon$ I say "huh, what's $\epsilon$???")

Comment: _the whole point_ is that for every $\epsilon>0$ etc. And that whole point is missing; there's no reason $\delta=1$ should imply $1/2|x|<1$, since you never told us that $|x-2|<\delta$.

Comment: I know I didn't fill in the details completely. I aware you have to make it more formal. The part is that if d = min(1, epsilon) then  |x-2|< d => |f(x)-L| < epsilon. I am just wondering if the d = min(1, epsilon) would work .

Comment: @Doug: I would say it's not the details, but the structure.  Thomas Andrews's comment is on point—the analysis you've done more or less asserts: "Well, in order to get $f(x)$ within this epsilon, I need to choose $x$ within this delta."  The proof basically runs this the other way: "Given an epsilon, let $x$ fall within this delta-window.  Then [algebraic manipulation omitted] $f(x)$ will fall within the epsilon-window."

Comment: P.S. It may seem persnickety to focus on this, but the underlying reason is logic: For many of the deductions, the inference only goes one way (e.g., if, but not only if).  So putting the argument in the "right" way is necessary to check, reliably, whether the choices work.

Answer (score 2):

No; this does not constitute a proof. What you have written are the steps towards finding a suitable $\delta$, but that isn't the proof. To prove the statement you would have to write something along the lines of

> Given $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta=\min(\epsilon,1)$. Suppose $\delta=1$. Then $$|x-2|<\delta \implies |x-2|<1 \implies \frac{1}{|2x|}<\frac{1}{2}<1$$
> So $$|x-2|<\delta \implies|x-2|<1 \implies\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\frac{1}{|2x|}<1\leq\epsilon$$
> Suppose $\delta=\epsilon$. Then $\epsilon<1$, so
> $$|x-2|<\delta \implies |x-2|<\epsilon \implies \frac{1}{|2x|}<\frac{1}{2(2-\epsilon)}<\frac{1}{2}<1$$
> So $$|x-2|<\delta \implies|x-2|<\epsilon \implies\left|\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<\frac{\epsilon}{|2x|}<\epsilon $$

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply. 
I know I didn't fill in the details completely and I am aware you have to make it more formal. My post was more of the rough work. I am just wondering if the d = min(1, epsilon) would work, from my rough work

Comment: @Doug Well, it will be hard to test it without writing the proof. If you want to see if it works, you should write out the proof then analyze it to see if there are any flaws. However, if there is an obvious counterexample to your choice of $\delta$, then that will save you time.